# Вернуть поток в начальное положение

Tags: java

Реализован конвейер, состоящий из `Manager`, `Reader`, `Executor1`, `Executor2`, `Writer`, наследованные от `Runnable` (`Executor1` дергает `Reader`, получает от него данные, обрабатывает, затем `Executor2` дергает `Executor1`, получает данные, обрабатывает и так далее).

`Manager` ставит объекты на конвейер в нужном порядке, затем запускает `Reader.run()`, который читает входной файл по кусочкам x байт и отдает его на обработку конвейеру.

Необходимо в менеджере создать n потоков `Thread(Executor1)`, которые запустит `Reader`, отдав каждому потоку x/n байт данных на обработку, которые в порядке очереди примет `Writer`и запишет в выходной поток.

Проблема в том, что после первой итерации созданные потоки закрываются после `Writer`, а нужно обработать целый файл. Как решить задачу, не создавая новые потоки, кроме тех n, которые в начале построения конвейера создал менеджер? Можно ли как-то возвращаться после записи в начало потока? Или кидать в поток новые данные еще до того, как старые успеют дойти до райтера и закончить запись (неясно как это реализовать)?

Код без тредов можно посмотреть [тут](https://github.com/adtsvetkov/Java/tree/v2.0/lab3)
или [тут](https://github.com/adtsvetkov/Java/tree/v2.0/lab2).

Comment: `while(true) { ждатьЗадание(); считать(); yield результат; }` Блин, не тот yield - кажется, джава не умеет генераторы.

Comment: Кому лень читать вопрос, краткая версия: **Как реализовать собственный ThreadPool?**

Comment: Теоретически в потоках можно реализовать бесконечный цикл и управлять их завершением из мененджера. А код можно посмотреть здесь или на github?

Comment: @Z.John, код без тредов можно посмотреть [тут](https://github.com/adtsvetkov/Java/tree/v2.0/lab3). Если слишком сложно и непонятно, то [тут](https://github.com/adtsvetkov/Java/tree/v2.0/lab2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, вы хотите выполнять какую-то логику в разных потоках над данными которые берете из одного файла и записывать результат обработки в другой файл.

Могу посоветовать сделать один поток - читатель файла - его задача, считывать данные и записывать куски в некую очередь допустим preQueu.

Несколько потоков обработки - мониторят данные в очереди preQueu, если она не пустая берут кусок на обработку и результат записывает в другую очередь postQueu, если preQueu пустая - поток засыпает на некоторое время, после чего опять проверяет очередь preQueu  и так в бесконечном цикле, пока менеджер не остановит поток.

Поток записи в файл - в бесконечном цикле (пока не остановит менеджер) мониторит очередь postQueu, если данные есть - записывает их в файл, если данных нет, то засыпает на некоторое время, после чего опять делает проверку.

Смущает только одна фраза:

> которые в порядке очереди примет Writer

как только вы сделаете обработку в несколько потоков, вы не можете им указать в каком порядке они должны завершаться, соответственно записывать в файл они будут в том порядке в каком завершать потоки обработки.