# Java: согласование thread'ов

Tags: java, многопоточность

Друзья, добрый день!
Взываю к помощи с многопоточностью в Java.
Стоит задача реализовать простейший конвейер, на котором стоят всего два работника - `Reader` и `Writer`. Конвейер создает `Manager`, знакомя работников друг с другом, затем создавая отдельные потоки для каждого работника и запуская их (соответственно, в `run()` у `Writer` бесконечный цикл, который ждет данных от `Reader`, и завершается, когда `Reader` пришлет условный `EOF`).

Менеджер выглядит примерно так:

```
threads = new ArrayList<>();
Thread readthread = new Thread(reader); //создаем тред для ридера
threads.add(readthread);

reader.addConsumer(writer); //знакомим работников
writer.addProducer(reader);

Thread writethread = new Thread(writer); //тред для райтера
threads.add(writethread);

for (Thread t : threads) { //запускаем треды в порядке добавления в лист
     t.start();
}
```

Проблема состоит в том, что отлаживать такое многопоточное приложение не получается, и при запуске программа просто виснет (непонятно, почему).

Если решить проблему с отладкой запуском только одного треда, а для второго насильно сделать `run()` так:

```
writethread.start();
reader.run();
```

Или так:

```
readthread.start();
writer.run();
```

***В отладке*** все работает, корректно завершается (из входного файла с текстом "abcdef" получаем ровно такой же выходной). 
Если же просто запустить этот код (который с одним-единственным тредом), он крашится ровно так же, как и с двумя потоками, причем из исходного файла с текстом "abcdef" получается "cdefef", после чего вечный цикл продолжается, не реагируя на присланный `Reader`'ом `EOF`.

*Код ридера с комментариями [тут](https://pastebin.com/K6QSVDww)*.

*Код райтера [тут](https://pastebin.com/TZp3J6WY)*.

*Код вспомогательной структуры `Triplet` [здесь](https://pastebin.com/cfXqkurv)*.

*Проект полностью [здесь](https://github.com/adtsvetkov/Java/tree/master/lab4_2)*.

Примечание: считывание делаем по две буквы (то есть файл "abcdef" будет прочитан за 3 считывания).

Собственно, вопрос в том, с чем проблема может быть связана и как грамотно ловить/отлаживать такие ошибки?

Использую Java 1.8.0, IDE Intellij Idea 14.1.7.

Спасибо!

Comment: это та же задача https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1062051/%d0%92%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5/1062237#1062237 ?

Comment: @Z.John, да, она самая. Проблема с записью в нужном порядке решена при помощи идентификации, из какого продюсера пришли данные, и слипом, пока данные из *каждого* продюсера не придут.
Только не работает...

Comment: Выложите последнюю версию на github, так сложно смотреть

Comment: @Z.John, код лежит [тут](https://github.com/adtsvetkov/Java/tree/master/lab4_2/src/com/company).

Comment: Если честно, в вашем коде ничего не понятно, даже чего вы пытаетесь сделать. Изобретено много своих велосипедов: свой объект хранения пары ключ-значения (Pairs) - когда можно использовать Properties. Конфигурацию обычно хранят в файле `app.properties`. Тогда и все данные из файла конфигурации загружаются одной строкой `properties.load(...)`. Пишите свой логгер, когда есть давно проверенный log4j и т.д. Возможно, конечно, так задание поставлено, но код у вас, мягко выражаясь, не читаемый. Все неоправданно переусложнено. А где можно само задание посмотреть?

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что у вас может быть произвольное количество читателей и писателей. Сколько читателей и писателей менеджер должен создать, он эти значения должен получить из файла конфигурации. Путь к файлу конфигурации менеджера указывается в командной строке при запуске приложения. Так?

Comment: Поскольку у вас несколько потоков должны читать один и тот же файл, то каждый из них должен заранее знать какую часть файла он читает. Допустим если читаем в три потока, то весь файл делим на три части. Писателям должно быть все равно кто данные прочитал в какой последовательности отработали потоки чтения, но они должны четко представлять в какую часть файла записать полученные куски.

Comment: @Z.John, задание [тут](https://github.com/kystyn/java/tree/master/pipeline). Да, с файлом конфигурации все верно - из него менеджер получает данные о работниках и их файлах конфигурации. 
Читатель один, писатель один, работников бесконечное множество.

Comment: Реализовал для примера многопоточную обработку файла здесь https://github.com/jlk191603/FileReadWriteThreadsExample, там нет логики обработчиков, но есть управление потоками. Файл порционно копируется. Там же есть описание. Можете взять как основу и докрутить свою логику, или поправить свое решение

Answer (score 0):

Разбираться довольно тяжело в твоём коде, поскольку всё очень сильно переусложнено.

Почему не останавливается, я тебе могу сказать точно - флаг `endofstreamflag` не помечен `volatile`, при этом значение в него пишется из потока ридера (через вызов `loadDataFrom`), а читается из потока райтера.

---

Зачем их знакомить? Асинхронная обработка будет намного проще, если их не знакомить.

```
reader.addConsumer(writer); //знакомим работников
writer.addProducer(reader);
```

Например, пусть reader грузит данные в очередь, а writer пишет на диск.

```
final var queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<byte[]>(1);
final var endoffile = "#EOF$".getBytes();

new Thread(() -> {
  try (var fis = new FileInputStream(filename)) {
    var buffer = new byte[readsize]; 
    while (fis.read((byte[])buffer) > 0) { // правильно работает только для файлов, чей размер кратен readsize
        queue.add(buffer);
        buffer = new byte[readsize]);
    }
    queue.add(endoffile);
  }
}).start();

new Thread(() -> {
  try (var fos = new FileOutputStream(outputfile)) {
    while(true) {
      var buffer = queue.get();
      if (Arrays.equals(buffer, endoffile)) break;
      fos.write(buffer);
    }
  }
}).start();
```

Comment: Это упрощенный вариант, на самом деле должно работать дерево из произвольного числа работников - для этого необходимо знакомство.
И с `volatile` пробовалось, и с использованием `AtomicInteger` - все равно циклится :(

Comment: Знакомство всегда 1:1? Если да, то код выше. Оборачиваешь в класс и создаёшь столько инстансов, сколько требуется

Comment: не всегда. У читателя может быть бесконечное число консумеров, у писателя - бесконечное число продюсеров.
У меня есть интерфейс, на котором мне нужно реализовать описанный функционал, поэтому я не могу отказаться от loaddatafrom, например. (описание [тут](https://github.com/kystyn/java/tree/master/pipeline)).

Comment: Привет преподу - более косноязычное описание трудно было бы составить. Так что, прошу прощения, но я умываю руки.